# Beautiful soup meta content tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
<meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="4103 Beach Bluff Rd">
```

I have to get the content '4103 Beach Bluff Rd'. I'm trying to get this done with `BeautifulSoup` so, I'm trying this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="4103 Beach Bluff Rd"> ')

soup.find(itemprop="streetAddress").get_text()
```

but I'm getting an empy string as result, which may have sense given that when a print the soup object

```
print soup
```

I get the this:

```
<html><head><meta content="4103 Beach Bluff Rd" itemprop="streetAddress"/> </head></html>
```

Apparently the data I want is in the 'meta content' tag, how can I get this data?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> `soup.find(itemprop="streetAddress").get_text()`

You are getting the text of a matched element. Instead, *get the "content" attribute value*:

```
soup.find(itemprop="streetAddress").get("content")
```

---

This is possible since `BeautifulSoup` provides a [dictionary-like interface to tag attributes](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

> You can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="4103 Beach Bluff Rd"> ')
>>> soup.find(itemprop="streetAddress").get_text()
u''
>>> soup.find(itemprop="streetAddress").get("content")
'4103 Beach Bluff Rd'
```