# Web-Scraping using BeautifulSoup (missing values when scraping)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to webscrape a realtor website using BeautifulSoup and encountered 2 difficulties that I cannot seem to fix.

**Difficulties:**

1. When I run my code below, I am missing some date values. The dataframe should hold 68 rows of data scraped from the first page. The description and title scrapes return 68 rows, but the date scrape returns 66. I don't get N/A values returned if its missing either. Does anyone have an idea why this is? When I inspected the website elements it had the same tags, except it is listed as VIP or Special (promotion) apartments.
2. Secondly, I cannot seem to figure out how to scrape **meta itemprop** tags. I keep getting blank values when I use:

```
for tag in soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'announcement-block-text-container announcement-block__text-container'}):
for tag2 in tag.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'announcement-block__date'}):
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance you could provide.

**Python Code:**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen,Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import ssl
import pandas as pd

def get_headers():
   #Headers
   headers={'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
           'accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
           'cache-control':'max-age=0',
           'upgrade-insecure-requests':'1',
           'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36'}
   return headers

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
count = 1 # for pagination

#Make list holder
title = []
description = []
date = []

urls = ['https://www.unegui.mn/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/5-r/']

for x in urls:
   count=1
   y=x
   while(count < 2):  # will get only 1st page
       print(x)
       req = Request(x, headers=get_headers())  #req all headers
       htmlfile = urlopen(req)
       htmltext = htmlfile.read()
       soup = bsoup(htmltext,'html.parser')
       
       for tag in soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'announcement-block-text-container announcement-block__text-container'}):
           for tag2 in tag.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'announcement-block__title'}):
               text = tag2.get_text().strip()
               if len(text) > 0:
                   title.append(text)
               else:
                   title.append('N/A')
               
       for tag in soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'announcement-block-text-container announcement-block__text-container'}):
           for tag2 in tag.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'announcement-block__description'}):
               text = tag2.get_text().strip()
               if len(text) > 0:
                   description.append(text)
               else:
                   description.append('N/A')
               
       for tag in soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'announcement-block-text-container announcement-block__text-container'}):
           for tag2 in tag.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'announcement-block__date'}):
               text = tag2.get_text().strip()
               if len(text) > 0:
                   date.append(text)
               else:
                   date.append('N/A')

       # Go to next page
       count=count+1
       page = '?page='+str(count)
       x=y+page

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(title,description,date)),columns=['Title', 'Description', 'Date'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get 66 items because your `date[]` contains only 66 elements, therefore, you need to check all three fields at once in one `for` loop. Your `if else` checks do nothing as there are no `announcement-block__date` divs with empty content on the page.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen,Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import ssl
import pandas as pd

def get_headers():
   #Headers
   headers={'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
           'accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
           'cache-control':'max-age=0',
           'upgrade-insecure-requests':'1',
           'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36'}
   return headers

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
count = 1 # for pagination

#Make list holder
info = {
    'title': [],
    'description': [],
    'date': []
}

urls = ['https://www.unegui.mn/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/5-r/']

for x in urls:
   count=1
   y=x
   while(count < 2):  # will get only 1st page
       print(x)
       req = Request(x, headers=get_headers())  #req all headers
       htmlfile = urlopen(req)
       htmltext = htmlfile.read()
       soup = bsoup(htmltext,'html.parser')
       for tag in soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'announcement-block-text-container announcement-block__text-container'}):
            title = tag.find('a', attrs={'class':'announcement-block__title'})
            description = tag.find('div', attrs={'class':'announcement-block__description'})
            date = tag.find('div', attrs={'class':'announcement-block__date'})
            info['title'].append(title.get_text().strip() if title else 'N/A')
            info['description'].append(description.get_text().strip() if description else 'N/A')
            info['date'].append(date.get_text().strip() if date else 'N/A')
       # Go to next page
       count=count+1
       page = '?page='+str(count)
       x=y+page

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(info['title'], info['description'], info['date'])),columns=['Title', 'Description', 'Date'])
print(len(info['title']), len(info['description']), len(info['date']))
print(data_frame)
```

About your second question, a similar question has already been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302774/beautiful-soup-meta-content-tag)

Comment: Thank you @ilusha. I found out the missing values but still trying to figure out how to fill in the date even though its in the same tag as the other dates. Then I have to figure out how to enter into the link for each apartment listing on the page, and get span tag data from the href links.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you wanted to say about dates, but you can get links from `title['href']`

Comment: Hi. I am still struggling to find the missing 2 date values for real estate posts listed as VIP. I am able to get all other columns, except the date for the 2 links. I inspected the webpage once more and found the same tags being used for the VIP section and the normal section of the webpage. Yet I cannot seem to figure out how to get the missing 2 date values. Additionally, how would I read inside each link and get the list span values? I apologize English is not my first language, and I thought I could post an updated code in my original post. Sorry for all the trouble and thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the meta content tag. I got it to work. I also fixed my missing date values. Now I am just trying to find how to get all href links and read inside each and every one of them. I chose your answer as correct (did not realize I had to hit the checkmark so I apologize) and created a new question. Once again thank you. If you perhaps have time could you check out my new question? Cheers! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69628412/web-scrapping-all-links-on-a-page-and-reading-data-from-each-link